# Firebase Android : How to get list inside specific child?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to retrieve inner list of specific child. Please refer following structure.

If I want to retrieve "servicesArrayList" for "recipient" where "billNo" is "135", What query I should be writing so that I can pass that query to [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) (firebase -ui)

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is for servicesArrayList for specific recipient.

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(RECIPIENT_NODE)
            .child(uid)
            .child("servicesArrayList")
            .orderByChild ?




recipient // parent Node

 2R1Q8qKEPHXFU1OiMq5TyxHBaZa2 // uId

   -KgJhMAWADwownv5tck6  // push Id
   -KgJhMAWADwownv5tck6
   -KgJoD77HQK-yACD_EuB
   -KgJoRXVUP_-Z0gLhIWy
   -KgJob82t47PvTjfTtig
   -KgK-N_Av_2kmmQS0Ulx

   -KgNu-fVWwFDLnRENj_b // Recipient Data
        billNo: 135
        billingMonth: "July 2017"
        childGender: "Ms."
        childName: "xyz"
        date: "29/03/2017"
        fineAmount: 0
        paymentStatus: "UNPAID"
        pushId: "-KgNu-fVWwFDLnRENj_b"
        receiptUrl:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ngf..."
        recipientEmail: "abc@gmail.com"
        recipientName: "Abc C."
        servicesArrayList
                 -0
                    -amount: 1000
                    -charges: "1000"
                    -noOfSessions: 1
                    -serviceType: "Speech And Language Assessment"

        total: 1000
        vat: 0
```

Comment: Do you only want value of `serviceArrayList` inside one push id only? like only in `-KgNu-fVWwFDLnRENj_b\serviceArrayList`. Or across all push id in `2R1Q8qKEPHXFU1OiMq5TyxHBaZa2`?

Comment: @koceeng only -KgNu-fVWwFDLnRENj_b\serviceArrayList not from all . Like  this query gives me all "unpaid" recipients only. Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(RECIPIENT_NODE)
                .child(uid)
                .orderByChild("paymentStatus")
                .equalTo("UNPAID");

Comment: Then have you tried `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(RECIPIENT_NODE).child(uid).child(pushId).child("servicesArrayList");`? The code know the target's pusId, right?

Comment: @koceeng That's perfect answer ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knnow the uid and the push id, then this should do it:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(RECIPIENT_NODE)
    .​child(uid).child(pus‌​hId).child("services‌​ArrayList");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

TRY this:

```
     Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(RECIPIENT_NODE)
            .child(uid).orderByChild("billNo").equalTo(135);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      Query query1= dataSnapshot.getRef().child("servicesArrayList");
       //pass this query to adapter of firebaseRecyclerAdapter      
     FirebaseRecyclerAdapter  adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<>(,,,query1){} 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to pass this "query" object to my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. I can use this if I want to extract "servicesArrayList" and then pass it to normal RecyclerAdapter.

Comment: You can extract serviceArraylist and then,pass it to normal RecyclerAdapter.

Comment: yes. As mentioned in my question I'm looking for appropriate query. Thanks !